# Node movement using random Uniform

Tags: tcl, ns2

I have a problem about node movement from initial position using random variable uniform in NS-2. My node position should be inside specified size with initial position like this :

```
if {($i >= [expr 0 * $STA]) && ($i < [expr 3 * $STA])} {
    $posX_ set min_ [expr 1 / 2 * $R]
    $posX_ set max_ [expr 3 / 2 * $R]
} elseif {($i >= [expr 3 * $STA]) && ($i < [expr 7 * $STA])} {
    $posX_ set min_ [expr 2 * $R]
    $posX_ set max_ [expr 3 * $R]
}
$wl_node_($i) set X_ [$posX_ value]

if {($i >= [expr 7 * $STA]) && ($i < [expr 8 * $STA])} {
    $posY_ set min_ 0
    $posY_ set max_ [expr 2 * $h]
} elseif {(($i >= [expr 3 * $STA]) && ($i < [expr 4 * $STA])) || (($i >= [expr 12 * $STA]) && ($i < [expr 13 * $STA]))} {
    $posY_ set min_ $h
    $posY_ set max_ [expr 3 * $h]
}
$wl_node_($i) set Y_ [$posY_ value]
```

Then, I want to move node position randomly but still in specified size using below code with $posX_ and $posY_ same with initial position

```
set val(x2) [$posX_ value]
set val(y2) [$posY_ value] 

$ns at 5.0 "$wl_node_($i) setdest $val(x2) $val(y2) 0.1"
```

But when I run, I get this error :

```
ns: _o9040 setdest 2.507944e+01 6.018404e+01 0.1: 
(_o9040 cmd line 1)
invoked from within
"_o9040 cmd setdest 2.507944e+01 6.018404e+01 0.1"
invoked from within
"catch "$self cmd $args" ret"
invoked from within
"if [catch "$self cmd $args" ret] {
set cls [$self info class]
global errorInfo
set savedInfo $errorInfo
error "error when calling class $cls: $args" $..."
(procedure "_o9040" line 2)
(SplitObject unknown line 2)
invoked from within
"_o9040 setdest 2.507944e+01 6.018404e+01 0.1"
```

How to solve this problem?

Thank you

Comment: This isn't your critical bug, but brace your expressions, and change `if {($i >= [expr 0 * $STA])…` to `if {($i >= (0 * $STA))…` (and if that breaks anything, your code is _horrible_ and needs much work).

Comment: can you post complete tcl script?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the `setdest` method is producing an error message with either an empty message or with the actual arguments as message (I can't tell which). You don't show the code in question, so working out — or even guessing — what the problem is would be really hard. (The obvious things — no such object, no such method, wrong number of arguments — don't appear to apply here, at least going by what I'd expect in Tcl error messages.)

However, I suggest trying to call the method immediately instead of postponing it, at least to see if that gives you a better error trace. Moving things to later in the simulation just adds to the complexity.